# How to avoid overlapping when using single quotes (German)

Tags: fonts, xetex

when using the following example I get (probably not surprisingly) overlapping between single quotes and the letter at the beginning of a word (for example starting with A) or the end of a word (for example ending with f).
Since I have to use the single quotes in this form quite a lot, how can I avoid this? Is is only font specific? If so, how can I avoid that with Adobe Garamond? Which options do I have to choose?

I am using XeLaTeX.

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[twoside=true, headsepline, 11pt, headings=small, ngerman, toc=graduated, mpinclude=false, headinclude, footinclude=false, ilines, BCOR=12mm, DIV=9]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[xetex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xunicode,fontspec,xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\begin{document}

‚Atlanta’

‚Begriff’
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem but simply an advice: Don't load xunicode before fontspec. Actually you don't need to load at all fontspec and xltxtra will do it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the font lacks proper kerning pairs for the RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK.

With

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{’}{\/’}
```

I get decent results.